# Shaded KML overlays on OSM tiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, kml, overlay, mapping

This seems simple - but the solution is escaping me.

I have a series of dynamically generated KML files describing simple, shaded polygons, with each polygon having a slightly different (externally calculated) color and transparency. After import, all features not contained within a polygon would be clipped off.

I'm trying to layer these onto a detailed street map, and thought QGIS might be able to do this.

QGIS doesn't seem to preserve the style attributes from imported KML files. I've tried multiple formats, including running it through an import -> export in Google Earth Pro.

Also, it doesn't appear there is a way to clip the OpenLayers road map tiles outside of the polygon overlay since the OpenLayers isn't showing as a vector layer.

Can QGIS do this or do I need a different piece of software or a web service?